# Picture from IPHONE with JPEG extension but seen as GIF in mime type on PHP server

Tags: php, iphone, responsive-design, getimagesize

I have a responsive web site with input of type "file" to upload pictures directly from iphone to the site. When doing so, Iphone send JPEG images but when received on PHP server, the getimagesize() function returms "images/gif" in Mime type and cause bugs in my image resizing process. Any clue on what's happening and how to solve that ? 
Thanks for all your hekp

Comment: in fact, oddly enough , some images had JPEG extension but in gif format. so I ended up considering the mimetype and no more the file extension.